# Formula 1 shooting (Hockenheim, Budapest)

Tags: digital

I want to shoot formula 1 races and just wonder if there is someone who already had such experience. So I want to go to German or Hungary to F1 GP this year and the questions are

1. Is it allowed for everyone to shoot there?
2. If so, is it allowed to bring a tripod or monopod to the grandstand?
3. Is it possible to get the media permit (I'm not a journalist) and shoot not from grandstand?

Thanks

Comment: It's unusual to get a media permit for any event without being able to demonstrate that a significant number of people will be looking at your photos  (e.g. a newspaper commission or a popular blog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a question about specific venue rules and regulations.  Beyond the rules you will have to contend with the fact that some tracks simply put spectators far from the action. To add to that the debris fence can interfere with many good angles.

As an example, for Hockenheim you can find the rules [here](http://www.hockenheimring.net/en/spectator-rules):

> Photography and filming at the Hockenheimring Baden-Württemberg is allowed only for private purposes and press purposes. Any form of commercial use of such image material is prohibited, and requires the written approval of Hockenheim-Ring GmbH. Contravention will result in claims for compensation for damages by Hockenheim-Ring GmbH. The house rules of Hockenheim-Ring GmbH apply. Photography and filming is generally allowed only from the grandstands, and for designated events also in the drivers’ camp. Persons obtaining access to the inner area of the course without a valid employee pass, accreditation pass or written approval of Hockenheim-Ring GmbH will be removed from the area, and will be responsible for the legal consequences. At major events, photography from the grandstands using SLR cameras with zoom lenses of any type is prohibited. The use of camera tripods of any type on the grandstands is also prohibited. The only exemptions to this rule are press photographers accredited for the relevant event who can identify themselves by means of a valid event press pass, or persons with corresponding written permission from Hockenheim-Ring GmbH. Applications for such approvals (commercial use) can be made by post to Hockenheim-Ring GmbH, code word: Photo rights, PO Box 1106, 68754 Hockenheim or by e-mail to presse@hockenheimring.de.

Answer (score 1):

I've been to Silverstone and Monza and whilst I didn't take any pictures myself (I needed a bit of a break) there were plenty of people there with tripods and some huge lenses (e.g. the Sigma 300-800). There are plenty of places you can shoot through the catch fencing and get good shots without any sort of press pass.

The key is to shoot during free practice, that way you can get to the best places, it's less crowded and you aren't spoiling anyone's view. I'm pretty sure Silverstone has the same "official" policy but I saw people shooting from grandstands with super telephotos  on the Friday, the stands were nowhere near full so nobody cared.

And Monza, well you can do whatever you like there!

Answer (score 0):

Starting by the end of your topic:
To get track acees you need to show up that you are a professional photographer. Otherwise you will never be there. Even when so, its not easy to get a Media tabbard, so I'd say forget it by now and focus on shooting for fun.

It is allowed to bring cameras and equipment. Not sure about monopods or tripods as they can be thrown away or be used as weapons i believe. Anyways, why would you like to bring a tripod? Probably it will be restricted by the fact that you can't record video, so I'd assume you'll not be allowed to bring a tripod.

Anyways enjoy your photos!

Comment: Hello and welcome to photo exchange. It seems that your answer might have be written on some facts you know, pls add some sources to it, so everyone can get access to it. But if your answer is just based on assumptions it would be good if you rewrite your answer.